# how to append a text in mvc view in an if clause

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to show a value if another value greater than 0. If this value

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => bankCollectionReportResult.OcakYuzde)
```

greater than 0 I will append with `"%"` and  `@Html.DisplayFor(model => bankCollectionReportResult.OcakYuzde)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this way:

```
@if(model.bankCollectionReportResult.OcakYuzde > 0)
{
   @Html.Raw("%"+model.bankCollectionReportResult.OcakYuzde)
}
```

Comment: Html.Raw should not be used spuriously

Answer (score 2):

you can do it like this

```
@{
    if (model.bankCollectionReportResult.OcakYuzde > 0)
    {
         @Html.DisplayFor(model => bankCollectionReportResult.OcakYuzde) %
    }
    else
    {
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => bankCollectionReportResult.OcakYuzde)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It may be overkill, but if you have to do this more than once, you could create your own helper.

```
//done with int there, but you could do with the desired type
public static IHtmlString DisplayConditionalPercent<TModel>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, int>> expression, int minimalDisplayValue = 0)
{
    int value;
    var displayValue = helper.DisplayFor(expression);
    if (int.TryParse(displayValue.ToString(), out value) && value > minimalDisplayValue)
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(displayValue + " %");
    return null;
}
```

usage

```
@Html.DisplayConditionalPercent(model => bankCollectionReportResult.OcakYuzde)
```

So you can change the "minimal" requirement to display whenever you want.

And you don't have an if else in your view.